# RestSharp: Execute<T>() with T having IEnumerable property

Tags: c#, restsharp

I noticed that using RestSharp :`Execute<T>()` , when T as below

```
public class Result
{
    public List<DBData> Data { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }           
}
```

It deserialized the JSON from `Execute<Result>()` correctly into Result object, 
However when the class has IEnumerable property like below

```
public class Result 
{
    public IEnumerable<DBData> Data { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

`Execute<Result>()` does not fill(deserialize) into the object Result.

I am suspecting it is because of `IEnumerable<T>` being read only and Restsharp is unable to deserialize data because of that ? Is it the case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because RestSharp can not infer the type of the property from the IEnumerable. Extend the existing SimpleJson serializer to use more robust serializer like [Json.Net](http://3OG/MIb1YTKHAo5Ljywnbbcis8TYV7vpMxOiRBbaDaJk0Bdd+hW0j7KibTGkPOOXbyyRq5rV2ta9N1JuNPVKcdoTYH59lzzBbXqw3UcPf25s9zvALIAmxeJPREmLDQgJQwQy+F5MCol/sKilFHlklg==)

Comment: So it is indeed to do with Interface properties. I found this link about the same:https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/201. Thanks!

Comment: Or you could just use `List` instead of IEnumerable